# SVG not displaying correctly in D3.js dataviz

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In [this datavisualization](http://bl.ocks.org/fdaudens/raw/67c38da03bd13c47b25c/), I have a curious problem : my svg is not correctly aligned with the whole container.

I'm using a viewbox:

```
var svg = d3.select("#viz")
.attr("viewBox", [
    margin.left,
    margin.top,
    (width+margin.left),
    (height+margin.bottom)
  ].join(" "))
.append("svg")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: can you put a screen shot of how it should be aligned? or the desired output

Comment: You've set a transform on your parent svg?  You've nested 3 svg tags? The viewbox has a `min-x` that's the same as your margin...  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: [Here's a little clean-up](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5ZsM396RdBVKayoSe7k?p=preview) on the SVG mark-up...

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly. Thank you very much. If I understand correctly, you changed the viewbox to fix the margins, and correctly nested the svgs? Once again, thank you very much for your help!